# how can I take total minutes from time?

Tags: command-line, scripts, time, date

My system displayed the time like this 10:42 when i input the command 
`date +%R`. I need to take in total minutes of the time. That means like this 642 minutes. Is there any command or shell script for displaying total time in minutes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To only get the total minutes of the day, I would use the following command:

```
$ date "+%H*60+%M" | bc
```

Example:

```
$ date +%R
09:30
$ date "+%H*60+%M" | bc
570
```

The trick is to format the `date` output to allow `bc` to interpret and calculate the formula.

Comment: If you use `echo $(date +"%H*60+%M") | bc`, it works also in zsh ;)

Comment: @A.B. One day I'll switch over to `zsh`

Comment: `date "+%H*60+%M" | bc` works just as well too.  Probably in just about any shell.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma: Simple, thanks. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

just bash:

```
IFS=: read hour min < <(date +%R)
echo $(( 60 * 10#$hour + 10#$min ))
```

Forcing both variables to be treated as base-10, to avoid the shell throwing errors for invalid octal numbers `08` and `09`

Comment: Yes, `echo $(( $(date "+%k * 60 + 10#%M") ))` is what I meant to say

Comment: Yeah nothing wrong with that. Maybe my answer is a little more ... instructional

Answer (score 3):

```
date +%R | awk -F ":" '{print ($1 * 60) + $2}'
```

Or

```
 echo $((($(date +%l) * 60 ) + $(date +%M)))
```

`date +%l` will get the hours , multiply with 60 and add minutes `date +%M`

Answer (score 2):

Using `date` and `bash`:

```
eval "$(date +'today=%F now=%s')"; midnight=$(date -d "$today 0" +%s);echo "$(((now - midnight) / 60))"
```

*Example*

```
$ date
Fr 10. Jul 08:45:05 CEST 2015

$ eval "$(date +'today=%F now=%s')"; midnight=$(date -d "$today 0" +%s);echo "$(((now - midnight) / 60))"
525
```

---

Using `date` and an the z-shell (zsh):

```
IFS=:; set -- $(date +%T); echo "$((($1 * 3600 + $2 * 60 + $3) / 60))"
```

*Example*

```
% date
Fr 10. Jul 08:40:53 CEST 2015

% IFS=:; set -- $(date +%T); echo "$((($1 * 3600 + $2 * 60 + $3) / 60))"
520
```

Comment: @DineshDhananjayan Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me an upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers ;)

Comment: I don't think your zsh answer is correct: `IFS=: set -- $(date +%T); echo $1`
returns `08:16:52` -- you'll need `IFS=:; set ...`

Comment: @glennjackman Ups and thank you, corrected. :\

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use IFS, you can do it this way:

```
date=$(date +'%l:%M')
read H M <<< ${date//[-: ]/ }
echo  "Total minutes: $(($H * 60 + $M))"
```

output is:

```
Total minutes: 593
```

Comment: I have corrected your answer. The error message was `bash: 9 17*60+: syntax error in expression (error token is "17*60+")`